# Testing an RSpec mock that is called twice

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, rspec

I have a validation module that I include in my controllers.

In my controllers for Admin actions they all inherit from an `AdminController` which calls `require_permission :admin` before each to make sure the current user is an admin.

In another one of my controllers I call `require_permission? :view_admins` to verify that the user has permission to view other admin's details. When I run the spec to test that `require_permission :view_admins` is called I get an error, saying that `require_permission` was called with `:admin`.

If I change my spec and add a test that `require_permission?` is called with `:admin` in my test that it is called with `:view_admins` then the spec passes. Is there a way to just test that it is called with `:view_admins`?

Here is the spec that is passing:

```
it 'requires view_admins permission' do
      expect(controller).to receive(:require_permission).with :admin
      expect(controller).to receive(:require_permission).with :view_admins
      get :admins
end
```

and the spec that is failing:

```
it 'requires view_admins permission' do
      expect(controller).to receive(:require_permission).with :view_admins
      get :admins
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way, IMO, would be to wrap all your admin-authenticated tests in a context which expect the `:admin` call.

```
describe MyController do
  context "when authenticated" do
    before do
      expect(controller).to receive(:require_permission).with :admin
    end

    it 'requires view_admins permission' do
      expect(controller).to receive(:require_permission).with :view_admins
      get :admins
    end
  end
end
```

If you don't want to do that, then you can use `allow` to eat all unexpected invocations of the method:

```
it 'requires view_admins permission' do
  allow(controller).to receive(:require_permission)
  expect(controller).to receive(:require_permission).with :view_admins
  get :admins
end
```

That being said, since these are controller tests, consider writing them as acceptance tests (which test behavior) rather than unit tests (which frequently test implementation). For example:

```
describe AdminController do
  context "when logged in as an admin" do
    let(:permissions) { [:admin] }
    before { login_with *permissions }

    describe "#admin" do
      subject { get :admin }

      context "with view_pages" do
        let(:permissions) { [:view_pages] }
        it { is_expected.to respond_with 200 }
      end

      context "without view_pages" do
        it { is_expected.to respond_with 403 }
      end
    end
  end
end
```